# How does UIManagedDocument find the default data model file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I've been following the CS193p's lectures on Core data and I've run into a problem when I'm inserting a new managed object.

The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception **'NSInternalInconsistencyException'**, reason: '+entityForName: could not
>   locate an entity named 'Card' in this model.'

I've created the "Card" entity in my data model file. However I have a feeling it isn't finding the data model file correctly, since removing that file all together give the same error. I'm wondering how I can find out whether it is due the UIManagedDocument object not finding the data model that is causing this error.

Here is what I'm doing in my controller class:

```
NSURL *docURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *databaseURL = [docURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Cards Database"];
self.cardsDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:databaseURL];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.cardsDatabase.fileURL path]]) {
    [self.cardsDatabase saveToURL:self.cardsDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }];
} else if (self.cardsDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
    NSLog(@"Closed");
    [self.cardsDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Opened");
            [self addSampleData];
        }
    }];
} else if (self.cardsDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
    NSLog(@"Normal");
}


- (void)addSampleData
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.cardsDatabase.managedObjectContext;

    [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        Card *card = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Card" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        card.title = @"Test Title";
    }];

    [self.cardsDatabase saveToURL:self.cardsDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    }];
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
Card *card = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Card" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the simulator(In device, remove the app), clean the build and run again.  That should resolve most of the issues related to 'could not locate entities'.

Comment: Ah you're right. Worked after I did a simulator content reset. I tried cleaning previously and it didn't work, but this definitely solved the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue may happen, when you updated your Core Data model, by changing names of attributes of entities, and then Run it without clean(delete) the app with the older Core Data model from  the device. Unless you are planning to use light migration or model mapping, please be aware it may happen whenever you Run the app